# How do i use pspki cmdlets without installing the Module components?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, certificate-authority, pki

i want to use the powershell pspki module cmdlets without installing the module components on my CA.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run PSPKI commands directly on CA server without installing the module there.

On the other hand, you always can install PSPKI module on a separate computer (maybe, CA admin's workstation) and invoke server commands against CA server remotely. This won't expose any security risks associates with 3rd party module on CA server.